# android kotlin cache directory equals to null?

Tags: android, kotlin, caching

I am working with cache in android/Kotlin and I need cache directory. But when I do:

```
val cacheDir = File(this.cacheDir, "http")
val cacheParams = CacheParams(10, GsonMapper(), cacheDir)
```

my app crashes saying: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache directory should be non-null

can anyone explain me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It maybe looks logical but if you're stuck and unable to see it this can be helpful.

You need to add manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

this way it can read cacheDir and it won't be null